# Replacement command for hb_takeover

Tags: linux, high-availability, drbd, heartbeat

I recently installed the latest DRBD on Ubuntu 10.04 and would like to issue a one-step command to test failover to demonstrate to the powers that be the simplicity of failing over. In previous versions, there was `/usr/lib/heartbeat/hb_takeover` now I have to demote the primary and then promote the secondary manually.

Is there a new one-step command for this process that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the hb_* scripts. They have moved to 
`/usr/share/heartbeat/`
For some reason, they didn't show with `locate` even after an `updatedb`